# How to fix mixed content error in Swagger?

Tags: django, swagger, gunicorn

I am running Django RF backend application on Gunicorn. 
When trying to fetch data from Swagger I get "TypeError: Failed to fetch"
In console this error is reported:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://****.com/swagger/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://****.com/v2/products/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I tried everything I found and could think of including:
Adding

```
secure_scheme_headers = {
    'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl',
    'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https',
    'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
```

to Gunicorn

and

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

to Django settings.

But nothing helps.

Swagger for Django: drf-yasg==1.12.1

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution. In Django settings add

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# Security Headers
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3600
```